# What are the sample spaces of the physical ensembles?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

When one has a probability distribution, one needs to specify a sample space where it is defined (it is actually define over the events space, but I think this detail is not important here). For example, for the canonical ensemble, the probability distribution is given by,

$$P(\omega)=\frac{e^{-\beta E(\omega)}}{\sum_{\omega\in \Omega}e^{-\beta E(\omega)}}
$$

where $\Omega$ is a sample space and $\omega$ an element of it. My question is how can I define $\Omega$ precisely. The same for the other main ensembles.

Thanks

Comment: It's the phase space, or, more generally, the configuration space.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, you don't actually *need* a sample space; you can define measures directly on the lattice of events, and do analysis directly with the random variables. Although if you really wanted you can invoke Stone's theorem to construct a formal sample space from the lattice of events. (the mathematical sledgehammer here is the notion of a Boolean topos, which gives you a 'copy of all of mathematics', except that the truth values are the events, rather than two-valued logic)

That said, I'm under the impression that for physical applications, phase space is a popular choice for the sample space.

Answer (score 0):

Like the definition of the Hamiltonian,
the definition of the state space $\Omega$ is problem-dependent.

For instance, as mentioned in another answer, $\Omega$ can be the
phase space $\mathbb{R}^{3n} \times \mathbb{R}^{3n}$ of an unconstrained
system of $n$ particles in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Another example is given by the Ising model on $\mathbb{Z}^d$, in which $\Omega = \{ \pm 1 \}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$ is the set of configurations of $\pm 1$ spins on $\mathbb{Z}^d$.

If you are considering a grand canonical ensemble, $\Omega$ will usually
have the form $\Omega = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \Omega^{(n)}$, where
$\Omega^{(n)}$ is some "$n$-particle state space''. For instance, for
a lattice gas, you may set $\Omega^{(n)} = \left\{ \omega : \mathbb{Z}^d \to \{ 0, 1 \} : \sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^d} \omega_x = n \right\}$, the set
of configurations of $n$ particles on $\mathbb{Z}^d$, where $\omega_x = 0$ or $1$ indicate the absence or presence of a particle.